# Kivy Dropdown not opening in ScreenManager but open in screen

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having issues to get a kivy.DropDown widget to work with a screen manager.

I am using the dropdown code that the kivy documentation provides, and add it to a screen widget, which I then add to a screen manager to display. The following code should reproduce the problem by itself.

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        anchor = AnchorLayout()
        anchor.anchor_x = "center"
        anchor.anchor_y = "center"
        anchor.size = self.size
        anchor.pos = self.pos

        dropdown = DropDown()
        for index in range(10):
            # When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually
            # (disabling the size_hint_y) so the dropdown can calculate
            # the area it needs.

            btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)

            # for each button, attach a callback that will call the select() method
            # on the dropdown. We'll pass the text of the button as the data of the
            # selection.
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))

            # then add the button inside the dropdown
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        # create a big main button
        mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))

        # show the dropdown menu when the main button is released
        # note: all the bind() calls pass the instance of the caller (here, the
        # mainbutton instance) as the first argument of the callback (here,
        # dropdown.open.).
        mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

        # one last thing, listen for the selection in the dropdown list and
        # assign the data to the button text.
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
        anchor.add_widget(mainbutton)

        self.add_widget(anchor)

sm = ScreenManager() # transition = NoTransition())
sm.add_widget(MyScreen(name='screen'))

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Why is it that if put in a screen widget inside a ScreenManager, the dropdown widget does not work? Clarifications are welcome.

PS:
For anybody finding this issue, you can use the spinner widget to have the same functionality already implemented.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. And show us the code that is not working, not the code that does work.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Code now should reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BigBadCoder try with: `mainbutton.bind(on_release= lambda *args: dropdown.open(mainbutton))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is due to garbage collection. The `dropdown` reference in your `__init__()` method is not saved (The `bind` uses a `weakref` which will not prevent garbage collection). So I think all you need to do is replace your `dropdown` local variable with a `self.dropdown` instance variable as:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        anchor = AnchorLayout()
        anchor.anchor_x = "center"
        anchor.anchor_y = "center"
        anchor.size = self.size
        anchor.pos = self.pos

        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        for index in range(10):
            # When adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually
            # (disabling the size_hint_y) so the dropdown can calculate
            # the area it needs.

            btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)

            # for each button, attach a callback that will call the select() method
            # on the dropdown. We'll pass the text of the button as the data of the
            # selection.
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))

            # then add the button inside the dropdown
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        # create a big main button
        mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(None, None))

        # show the dropdown menu when the main button is released
        # note: all the bind() calls pass the instance of the caller (here, the
        # mainbutton instance) as the first argument of the callback (here,
        # dropdown.open.).
        mainbutton.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)

        # one last thing, listen for the selection in the dropdown list and
        # assign the data to the button text.
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
        anchor.add_widget(mainbutton)

        self.add_widget(anchor)

sm = ScreenManager() # transition = NoTransition())
sm.add_widget(MyScreen(name='screen'))

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Still, why does the weakref die out if the screen is in a screenmanager, but is kept alive if it's only a screen? DO you have any idea about that?

Comment: I see that behavior, but only when `Mycreen()`  is called outside the `build()` method (i.e., the `DropDown` fails). But if `MyScreen()` is called within the `build()` method, it works. Why it works that way is a mystery to me.

Comment: Actually, after testing a bit, it seems to randomly work now and then, and sometimes fail, regardless of where the `MyScreen()` creation occurs. But I did verify that the failure is due to `dropdown` reference not existing when the `mainbutton` is released.